# dynamically new added fields are overlapping

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textfield

Coming from C# i am very new in Java GUI. I am trying to create fields which shd dynamically add on pressing Input button "Add Inputs". But problem is when i press button for input and write something and then again press input for new field the previous field gets disappear and i have no idea why this is happening.

Right now i have border layout.

code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    private JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();

    private JButton startBtn = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton pauseBtn = new JButton("Pause");
    private JButton resumeBtn = new JButton("Resume");
    private JButton stopBtn = new JButton("Stop");
    private JButton resetBtn = new JButton("Reset");

    private JButton greenBtn = new JButton("Green");
    private JButton redBtn = new JButton("Red");



    private CountTimer cntd;
    private final JButton addInputs = new JButton("Add Inputs");


    public GUI() {
        setTimerText("         ");
        GUI();
    }

    private void GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        BorderLayout bl_panel = new BorderLayout();
        bl_panel.setVgap(200);
        bl_panel.setHgap(10);
        panel.setLayout(bl_panel);
        timeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        panel.add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        startBtn.addActionListener(this);
        pauseBtn.addActionListener(this);
        resumeBtn.addActionListener(this);
        stopBtn.addActionListener(this);
        resetBtn.addActionListener(this);
        greenBtn.addActionListener(this);
        redBtn.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel cmdPanel = new JPanel();
        cmdPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        cmdPanel.add(startBtn);
        cmdPanel.add(pauseBtn);
        cmdPanel.add(resumeBtn);
        cmdPanel.add(stopBtn);
        cmdPanel.add(resetBtn);

        panel.add(cmdPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        addInputs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.add(new JTextField(10));
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.validate();

            }
        });

        cmdPanel.add(addInputs);

        JPanel clrPanel = new JPanel();
        clrPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        clrPanel.add(greenBtn);
        clrPanel.add(redBtn);

        panel.add(clrPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

        cntd = new CountTimer();

    }

    private void setTimerText(String sTime) {
        timeLabel.setText(sTime);
    }


    private void setTimerColor(Color sColor) {
        timeLabel.setForeground(sColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();

        if (btn.equals(greenBtn))        { setTimerColor(Color.GREEN.darker()); } 
        else if (btn.equals(redBtn))     { setTimerColor(Color.RED); }
        else if (btn.equals(startBtn))   { cntd.start(); }
        else if (btn.equals(pauseBtn))   { cntd.pause(); }
        else if (btn.equals(resumeBtn))  { cntd.resume(); }
        else if (btn.equals(stopBtn))    { cntd.stop(); }
        else if (btn.equals(resetBtn))   { cntd.reset(); }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
               new GUI();
             }
          });

    }

    private class CountTimer implements ActionListener {

        private static final int ONE_SECOND = 1000;
        private int count = 0;
        private boolean isTimerActive = false;
        private Timer tmr = new Timer(ONE_SECOND, this);

        public CountTimer() {
            count=0;
            setTimerText(TimeFormat(count));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (isTimerActive) {
                count++;
                setTimerText(TimeFormat(count));
            }
        }

        public void start() {
            count = 0; 
            isTimerActive = true;
            tmr.start();
        }

        public void resume() {
            isTimerActive = true;
            tmr.restart();
        }

        public void stop() {
            tmr.stop();
        }

        public void pause() {
            isTimerActive = false;
        }

        public void reset() {
            count = 0;
            isTimerActive = true;
            tmr.restart();

        }

    }

    private String TimeFormat(int count) {

        int hours = count / 3600;
        int minutes = (count-hours*3600)/60;
        int seconds = count-minutes*60;

        return String.format("%02d", hours) + " : " + String.format("%02d", minutes) + " : " + String.format("%02d", seconds);
    }
}
```

I am also adding screen shot for better understanding:
when running:
[image]

after pressing Add Input and entering
[image]

now when i again press Add Input i lost previous input field
[image]

Comment: If you want to show multiple components in the GUI, make sure the layout manager is properly setup.  Using add() with the BorderLayout manager without specifying where will use the CENTER.

Comment: Use another [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for `panel`, such as [Grid Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [Box Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box). `BorderLayout` if you don't pass it a parameter will add it to `CENTER`, then it will place other components above the others

Comment: i tried but my button ran away somewhere

Comment: anyone!????????????????????????